# how to deallocate binary in a single process before the process terminated?

Tags: erlang

Generally, binary will deallocate automaticly when the count reference is none, but how to deallocate binary in a single    process,before the process terminated?? 
     thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang uses reference counting for keeping track of where binaries are used. Whenever a process creates a binary, the count goes up, and whenever it is sent to another process, yet another increment is made. As the processes stop using the binary (i.e. don't keep any variables bound to it anymore), the count will decrease.

Whether a binary is used by a single process or multiple ones doesn't really matter, since when the reference count is zero, the binary is automatically garbage collected. Therefore, even if you only use the binary in a single process, the Erlang VM will handle it for you.

In fact, the general "rule" to apply is that *a binary is, like any other data type in Erlang, automatically garbage collected*.

Comment: when using the code below to deallocate binary,but it does not active?  why? :

       B1= << 0:(1024*1024*1000) >>.
       garbage_collect(self()).

Comment: Erlang is a uses *reference counted* garbage collection. Just stop using the variable containing the binary or exit the current process, and it will be cleaned automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't deallocate binary manually.

Comment: rule is simple - if one else (client1) has reference to binary and you deallocate this binary then after deallocation client1 will have dangling pointer to binary and will get SIGSEGV on next access to binary.